# Webservice call gives an error. in react-native

Tags: react-native

*I call webservice like this :*

```
fetch('url', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
                          Accept: 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
                }),
            })
            .then((response) =>  response.text())
            .then(leaders => {
              console.log("leader = ", leaders);
}
```

*but this give me an error like this :*

```
Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Comment: What are you passing into collection?

Comment: Oh I am not passin I ll edit question. because I dont need to pass parametras.  Server dont have password  or username

Comment: I edited bro. I use this code

Comment: I think issue in passing header. Check my answer and do let me know if its work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
  fetch('url', {
                method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
                body: JSON.stringify(collection) // <-- Post parameters
                })
                .then((response) =>  response.text())
                .then(leaders => {
                  console.log("leader = ", leaders);
    }
```

or you can directly call like:

```
   fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
```

Comment: second one not work it gives error.  first is gives still 'Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Root element is missing.'

Comment: what does it mean 'root element is missing' ?

Comment: Something is missing while connecting with your server

Comment: How Can I solve this. I dont know what I should add. my webservise doesnt include password or username. so I dont send use  'body'

Comment: Any possibility to send me your url.